# Django double-escaping titles in podcasts

Tags: django, itunes, podcast, django-syndication

I'm using Django 1.2, and am having trouble generating good XML for a podcast. Any titles containing single-quotes, double-quotes or ampersands appear to be double-escaped, looking like this:

```
<title>Podcast: &amp;quot;But we had hoped...&amp;quot;</title>
```

Which means that they show up like this:

```
Podcast: &quot;But we had hoped&quot;
```

I did find [this ticket](http://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/6533), but it was closed ages ago.

I'm generating my feed using [this snippet](http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/2112/), and I'm just stuffing a value in a model field into the `self.title` bit, like this:

```
class iTunesPodcastPost():
  def __init__(self, talk):
    self.id = talk.id
    self.approval_date_time = talk.created
    self.title = talk.title # Looks wonky
    self.summary = talk.details # Looks fine
    self.enclosure_url = talk.mp3.url
    self.enclosure_length = talk.mp3.size
    self.enclosure_mime_type = u'audio/mpeg'
    self.duration = '%s' % talk.seconds
    self.explicit = u'clean'
    self.info_url = talk.get_absolute_url()
```

In case it helps, the podcast feed is [here](http://www.centralbaptistchelmsford.org/sermons/podcasts/itunes/podcast.xml).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This appears to have been because I failed to provide an `item_title` method on my `Feed` subclass.

Once I added:

```
def item_title(self, item):
   return item.title
```

All was well. Previously it had been defaulting to calling my item's `__unicode__` method with bizarre results. Not an entirely satisfactory solution (I still don't know why it broke), but at least it works now.